# How to retrieve data from mysql table

Tags: php, dart, flutter

With Flutter, I retrieved data from a mysql table in a `listview`. When the user presses an item in the list, I open a screen. My problem is that I want to retrieve links from the database images based on the `ID` of the element and display them on this page. Like `SELECT ..... WHERE idimg = 'CA109'` only that `idimg` changes according to the element chosen in the list. How can I make `idimg` dynamic in php code

```
SELECT 
    image
FROM
    ImageTable
WHERE
    idimg = 'CA109';
```

Comment: "php code"? why does the question then have dart and flutter tags?

Comment: it's just because I'm using Flutter

Comment: how do you do it exactly? For Flutter dart is used basically, and not php, for sure. Do you have a client side as a mobile app and a server side written on php?

Comment: here is the code i'm using.
```final response =
        await http.get("http://mybomain.com/php/get_data.php");
    return json.decode(response.body);```